# Pass value by reference in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pass-by-reference

I have a dictionary:

```
foo = {"a": self.x}
```

I want to change an object's value of `self.x` and not just the value saved within the dictionary. How would I do this?

Comment: You can't. Even if the x attribute was a property, what's in the dictionary is the result of calling the getter. Could you give some context - why do you want that?

Comment: @balderman that just changes what's in the dictionary, not what the x attribute's value is.

Comment: `foo["a"].x = "new value"`   ??  whats the `self` doing in here. can you provide a little more context ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, the result of `self.x` is stored in the dictionary as value like `10` for example. here `10` has nothing to do with your instance and also there is no relationship between the dictionary `foo = {"a": 10}` and the actual object.

In order to change your instance variable you have to have an access to the "instance" itself. something like :

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10

instance = C()
print(instance.x)

foo = {"a": instance}

foo['a'].x = 20

print(instance.x)
```

output :

```
10
20
```